# Installing WebLogic 12 on laptop

Tags: weblogic12c

I have been tasked to develop some Java web services which are going to be run on WebLogic on a Windows 2008 server. I don't know the WebLogic version, but I guess it should be version 12.

I have a laptop with Windows 7 Enterprise (32-bit). I also already have JDK 7 on C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25. I would prefer that I have WebLogic installed on my laptop. From the following website:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/weblogic/downloads/wls-for-dev-1703574.html

I would like to know:

(1) Does my laptop meet the requirement to install this version of WebLogic?

(2) Does it require administration rights to install?

On my background: I have Java experience including developing Java web applications and using WebLogic. But I have never done any web services before and the last time that I have done any development on Java web application was quite a number of years ago.

Answer (score 0):

From link you can download zip distribution for "Oracle WebLogic Server 12.1.3" and it supports jdk 1.7 .
For latest version of Weblogic 12.2.1 you would need jdk1.8.
1 GB ram dedicated for running 1 weblogic server will be fine .

Comment: If I install JDK 1.8, would I be able to install version 12.2.1 as my laptop is 32-bit?

Comment: 32-bit should not be a problem for development mode . You should be able to use WLS 12.2.1 zip distribution if jdk 1.8 is there.

Answer (score 0):

WLS 12.1.x requires JDK7 if you run WLS 12.2.1 you can run JDK8.

From version 12.x.x admin rights are needed to install the software.